# AM2302 using without Adafruit Library

Tags: raspbian

Hei, I am working on a project where I would like to use AM2302 for finding the humidity and temperature. I want to do this without using Adafruit libray, so i did some research and found that AM2302 is sending like 40 bits data only when a start signal from MCU is sent. So the question is how i send from a raspberry PI 4 the start signal and how i store from GPIO input the 40 bits data.
Thank you!

Comment: The AM2302 is software compatible with DHT22 - https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/105549/8697 should work (much more reliably than the Adafruit Library)

Comment: Ah, yes, if AM2302 gets the start signal, it will send 40 bits data results back. You might like to see how I use Rpi python MCP23017 to send the start signal, and get AM2302's 40 bits data back. https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=77158&hilit=AM2302+tlfong01&start=350#p1355771 I did it the hard way, using MCP23017 GPIO pin to send the start signal. I guess using Rpi GPIO is many times easier.

Comment: Thank you! i will try and let you know if i did it.