# DHT 11 sensor not found, check wiring

Tags: python, pi-2, sensor, adafruit

[image]I am using raspberry pi 4 model b and sensor DHT 11 for checking the humidity and temperature. When I am using the code [DHT.py](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/code/DHT.py), the result is:

```
1604263139.922  4 3 0.0 0.0
1604263142.192  4 3 0.0 0.0
1604263144.463  4 3 0.0 0.0
1604263146.732  4 3 0.0 0.0
1604263149.002  4 3 0.0 0.0
1604263151.273  4 3 0.0 0.0
1604263153.544  4 3 0.0 0.0
1604263155.816  4 3 0.0 0.0
```

but when I run my own code by using the command of
`python3 q1.py -f 5 -p 20 -o test.csv` :

```py
from board import D4
import adafruit_dht
import argparse
import datetime

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('-f',type=float)
parser.add_argument('-p',type=float)
parser.add_argument('-o',type=str)

args = parser.parse_args()

num_samples = int(args.p / args.f )


dht_device = adafruit_dht.DHT11(D4)

fp = open(args.o, 'w')

for i in range(num_samples):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    temperature = dht_device.temperature
    humidity = dht_device.humidity
    ptint(now.day,temperature,humidity,file = fp)
    time.sleep(args.f)
    
fp.close()
```

the error is :

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "q1.py", line 23, in <module>
    temperature = dht_device.temperature
  File "/home/pi/WORK_DIR/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/adafruit_dht.py", line 253, in temperature
    self.measure()
  File "/home/pi/WORK_DIR/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/adafruit_dht.py", line 205, in measure
    raise RuntimeError("DHT sensor not found, check wiring")
RuntimeError: DHT sensor not found, check wiring
```

the datasheet of sensor is [DFR0067 DFROBOT](https://wiki.dfrobot.com/DHT11_Temperature_and_Humidity_Sensor__SKU__DFR0067_)
[image]
[image]

boot/config.txt

```
# For more options and information see
# http://rpf.io/configtxt
# Some settings may impact device functionality. See link above for details

# uncomment if you get no picture on HDMI for a default "safe" mode
#hdmi_safe=1

# uncomment this if your display has a black border of unused pixels visible
# and your display can output without overscan
#disable_overscan=1

# uncomment the following to adjust overscan. Use positive numbers if console
# goes off screen, and negative if there is too much border
#overscan_left=16
#overscan_right=16
#overscan_top=16
#overscan_bottom=16

# uncomment to force a console size. By default it will be display's size minus
# overscan.
#framebuffer_width=1280
#framebuffer_height=720

# uncomment if hdmi display is not detected and composite is being output
#hdmi_force_hotplug=1

# uncomment to force a specific HDMI mode (this will force VGA)
#hdmi_group=1
#hdmi_mode=1

# uncomment to force a HDMI mode rather than DVI. This can make audio work in
# DMT (computer monitor) modes
#hdmi_drive=2

# uncomment to increase signal to HDMI, if you have interference, blanking, or
# no display
#config_hdmi_boost=4

# uncomment for composite PAL
#sdtv_mode=2

#uncomment to overclock the arm. 700 MHz is the default.
#arm_freq=800

# Uncomment some or all of these to enable the optional hardware interfaces
dtparam=i2c_arm=on
#dtparam=i2s=on
dtparam=spi=on

# Uncomment this to enable infrared communication.
#dtoverlay=gpio-ir,gpio_pin=17
#dtoverlay=gpio-ir-tx,gpio_pin=18

# Additional overlays and parameters are documented /boot/overlays/README

# Enable audio (loads snd_bcm2835)
dtparam=audio=on

[pi4]
# Enable DRM VC4 V3D driver on top of the dispmanx display stack
dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
max_framebuffers=2

[all]
#dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
```

Comment: Your wiring is probably wrong (as suggested). It definitely SHOULDN'T be connected to 5V

Comment: I corrected it but still isn't working

Comment: Does Joan's code work? No one can tell what pins the module uses - there is no standard.

Comment: yes if I run DHT.py, I can see the result

Comment: put heatshrink tubing over the bare wire connectors

Comment: @jsotola I don't have any instrument, Actually I am new to raspberry

Comment: I can't see anything wrong.  Have you got a link to the datasheet for your module?

Comment: @joan sensor or board? https://wiki.dfrobot.com/DHT11_Temperature_and_Humidity_Sensor__SKU__DFR0067_

Comment: Also, I change the green wire in place of red as what it is mentioned in the datasheet and still, nothing is working

Comment: Okay.  The green wire is data out and should be connected to a GPIO (say GPIO 4, pin 7).  Red should be connected to 3V3.  Black to ground.  If you use GPIO 4 make sure you don't have the 1-wire bus enabled as the 1-wire bus will talk on GPIO 4.

Comment: You say "yes if I run DHT.py, I can see the result" but if this is `1604271754.322  4 3 0.0 0.0` there is no DHT11 detected.

Comment: @Milliways really? is it possible that the sensor or the wire is broken?

Comment: @joan how can I check ```make sure you don't have the 1-wire bus enabled```

Comment: Check with raspi-config or look through /boot/config,txt or add the contents of /boot/config.txt to your question (or all three).

Comment: @joan I added the boot/config.txt to my question

Comment: No 1-wire in there.  As long as you wired it as I suggested (green to GPIO, red to 3V3, black to ground) it should work.  Perhaps it was damaged when wired incorrectly.  Try a different GPIO rather than 4.

Comment: @joan red is into 5V but anyway I was test 3v3, how can I check that which one is damaged? wire or sensor?

Comment: https://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Testing

Comment: @joan yes it's ok , i've tested and the board is ok

Comment: It's a good idea to put the plastic shells on those dupont connectors as well. If the 5V and GND make contact, you'll have a fully baked raspberry pi on your hands.

Answer (score 1):

I think (unless you have not corrected it yet) you have your wires wrong. The green one is the signal (data) and you have it connected to the 3V3.

[image: Example how to connect to DFRduino]

Source: [DFRobot - SEN0137 DHT22 Temperature and humidity module](https://wiki.dfrobot.com/DHT22_Temperature_and_humidity_module_SKU_SEN0137#target_1)

*Hint:*
Try running it in the loop like in the [dht_simpletest.py](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_DHT/blob/master/examples/dht_simpletest.py) - as @Milliways mentioned the python library is not stable.

Running in the loop and printing exceptions will give you more debug info - for my Pi Zero v1.3 this message was printed among others - misreported, see: [issue-33](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_DHT/issues/33).

Answer (score 0):

The Adafruit code is notoriously unreliable.

I use Joan's code, but have written a wrapper around it to facilitate getting a single reading.

This is easy to modify and include in your own code.

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/117225/8697