# Python import won't succeed when script is exec() from Apache PHP

Tags: python, php, apache-httpd, modules, dht22

I have a Python3 script (readtemp.py) to read temperature and humidity of a DHT22. I'm using adafruit_dht module. it executes perfectly from terminal command line with:

```
    python3 readtemp.py
```

or

```
    ./readtemp.py
```

At the head of the Python script I have:

```
    #!/usr/bin/python3
    import time
    import board
    import adafruit_dht
```

I put a line in Apache PHP:

```
$output = exec("python3 ./readtemp.py");
```

or

```
$output = exec("./readtemp.py");
```

or

```
$output = shell_exec("python3 ./readtemp.py");
```

or

```
$output = shell_exec("./readtemp.py");
```

and all work but when the page loads the Python script is executed but the import gets an error. In apache error.log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./readtemp.py", line 4, in <module>
    import adafruit_dht
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'adafruit_dht'
```

It looks like apache isn't letting python load an external module. Any ideas to get apache to allow python access the exeternal modules?

Comment: Have you installed the module adafruit_dht using pip3?

Comment: Yes, it was installed with pip3

Comment: Did you use `sudo pip3 ...` so that the module is available for all users?

Comment: yes, sudo was used to install.

Comment: Just to check, I sudo pip3 uninstall...   then then installed again with sudo pip3 install...   Now apache PHP page hangs on the exec() and never goes on to the rest of the PHP and nothing shows in the apache error.log.

Answer (score 1):

If you search this Forum you will find MANY questions about DHT22.

The Adafruit code is notoriously unreliable and **CAN NOT** be run from PHP because it requires root access.

See [Reliable temperature/humidity logging with Python and a DHT11](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/117225/8697) for the code I use.

Comment: Thanks again.  Works great and my application is running on the webserver.