# Cannot SSH into periphery RPis from master RPi using python script automated from crontab: Host key verification failed

Tags: ssh, cron, services

## Project Overview

I have a series of RPi 3B+ which collect T/RH data using connected sensors. These "periphery" units collect data every 5 minutes, append the data to a CSV file that holds a day's worth of data, and stores the data locally in a /data/ directory.

I have a "master" RPi 3B+ whose job is to periodically (approximately every 15 minutes) connect to these periphery units via SSH and copy the available data from the /data/ directory, process it, generate figures, and push these figures to GitHub.

The master RPi has been set up to connect without a password to the periphery units via `ssh-copy-id`. I was able to ssh into the periphery units from the master and, through that, stored the periphery units in the /home/pi/.ssh/known_hosts directory.

## The Problem

I created a script to automate this process and it works perfectly when I manually run it. The code used to connect to each device and download the data is shown below:

```py
os.system(f'scp -r -o ConnectTimeout=3 pi@{ip_address}:{path_to_raw} {self.path_to_data}/interim/')
```

I have run the script successfully both within and outside a virtual environment. **The problem** happens when I try to schedule the script via /etc/crontab. When I do this, the master can no longer connect to the periphery units with the error `Host key verification failed.` The `/etc/crontab` file is below:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# Example of job definition:
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7) OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  * user-name command to be executed
#*/5 * * * * root sh /home/pi/bleed-orange-measure-iaq/update_figures.sh
*/5 * * * * root /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/bleed-orange-measure-iaq/src/data/make_dashboard.py
```

The first command I have commented out was my attempt to run the script by wrapping it in a shell script but that was also unsuccessful so I figured I would just execute the python command.

## The Question

My question is why can I not connect to the periphery units when I place the script within crontab or in a service file? I understand now that the cron and login environments are different, but I have supplied both a `PATH` environment variable and used full path names.

Comment: Why do you run the cron as root? Try with your username.

Comment: The issue is where `ssh` looks for the host key. The host key is stored in the `known_hosts` file. The `known_hosts` file is stored in `/home/pi (or your username)/.ssh/` folder when you use `ssh` as the normal user. In the cronttab you use the script as `root`. In that case `ssh` looks for `known_hosts` in the folder `/root/.ssh/`. It does not find that file or the particular entry in the file `known_hosts` for `root`, as the host is "unknown" to the `root`.

Comment: It seems you have edited `crontab` with `sudo crontab -e`. This created a crontab for the `root`. You can revert the change and use `crontab -e` as the normal user `pi` or `fritz` or whatever, and put the line there, then the `scp` will run as the user, and not root.

Comment: Welp. The issue was the user. Running the cronjob as `pi` worked. Thank you for pointing out that there are multiple locations for the `known_hosts` file.

Comment: Let me convert my comment to an answer. Then you can accept the answer as correct with a green check mark next to it. This will help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## the Problem

The issue is where `ssh` (and `scp`) looks for the **host key**. The host key is stored in the `known_hosts` file. The `known_hosts` file is stored in `/home/pi/.ssh/` or `/home/fritz/.ssh/` folder when you use `ssh` as the normal user.

In the `cronttab` you use the script as `root`. In that case `ssh` looks for `known_hosts` in the folder `/root/.ssh/`. It does not find that file or the particular entry in the file known_hosts for root, as the host is "unknown" to the root.

## `crontab` as normal user

It seems you have edited `crontab` with `sudo crontab -e`. This created a crontab for the user `root`. Since `root` is not the usual user who uses `ssh` and `scp` The host_key verification is not stored in this user's "home" folder.

When you prefix any command with `sudo` you temporarily become the user `root` for that command.
With the `sudo crontab -e` you have created a cronjob for the user `root`.

## Files (Do not edit directly)

When you use the command `sudo crontab -e` you indirectly create/edit the file `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root`

When you use the command `crontab -e` you indirectly create/edit the file `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/pi`

**Do not edit these files directly using a text editor.** Always use the `crontab -e` or `sudo crontab -e`.

System services and applications place system-wide cron jobs in the file `/etc/crontab`.

Here is more on using `crontab -e` and editing the `/etc/crontab` file: https://superuser.com/questions/290093/difference-between-etc-crontab-and-crontab-e

### An Analogy

It is like becoming the acting manager for a day when the manager is sick and logging in with your manager's userID and password when you are the acting manager.

Now the manager's home folder does not have all the folders and files your home folder has. So if you look for a file in the manager's home folder, that you saved in your home folder yesterday (such as `known_hosts`) you will not find it there, because today you are logged in as the manager, yesterday you were logged in as yourself.

Think you using `sudo` prefix as logging in as the acting manager. The `sudo crontab -e` is like editing the manager's calendar and add a recurring meeting for the manager every Friday when you meant to put that meeting in your own calendar.

### Solution

You can revert the change and use `crontab -e` as the normal user `pi` or `fritz` or whatever, and put the line there, then the scp will run as the normal user, and not `root`.

## Don't `ssh` as `root`

Alternately you can try `ssh` into the remote server as `root` manually first with this command:

```
sudo ssh pi@<ip address of the other pi>
```

This may not work as `ssh` as the `root` with the `rot's password is disabled by default because it is a security risk. The root user may not have a password assigned for the same security reasons.

hope this helps

Comment: This was indeed my issue. However, I edited the crontab with `sudo nano /etc/crontab`. Could you explain briefly what the difference between that and `crontab -e` is? Looks like the files are different.

Comment: @FruityFritz I have added the explanation. Let me know if this is clear.

Comment: Oh no I understand (to a certain extent) what using `sudo` does. My question was what is the difference between editing cron through `/etc/crontab` versus through `crontab -e`?

Comment: @FruityFritz I have added the exact files edited by the two commands.

Answer (score 1):

You've edited your question, and several things in my answer are now  [passé](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/passe). You've also accepted an answer now, and I will take that to mean you've got your objective system/software working. I'll just take this opportunity to address a few points:

#### 1. user crontabs

Every user (by default) gets the ability to create his own `crontab`, which means the user can schedule and run `cron jobs`. These jobs are "limited" by the user's *permissions*, `group` memberships, and all of the usual security protections that are built into Linux.

#### 2. if a cron job requires root privileges:

Wrt `cron` jobs run by user `pi` on a Raspberry Pi, you should know a bit of history, and understand its implications:

- Under *previous defaults* in RPi distros, user `pi` was already added to the `sudo` group, and also configured with the `NOPASSWD` option. Those defaults were changed earlier this year (2022). The `NOPASSWD` option was significant for `cron` users because it meant that they could successfully use `sudo` in user `pi`'s `crontab`. *This was an aberration*; I know of no other Linux distro that does this *by default*. The unfortunate result of this `NOPASSWD` default for `sudo` is that some Pi users didn't understand that ***sudo shouldn't be used in a `crontab`***. So - if you see `sudo` used in questions or answers here, you should know that this is not the way to run `cron` jobs with `root` privileges - such jobs should be run from `root`'s `crontab`:

  ```bash
  sudo crontab -e
  ```

  Also know that running a job from `root`'s `crontab` means that `sudo` is **not required** - *everything* runs with `root` privileges. *Use appropriate caution*.
- ICYI, this `NOPASSWD` option was configured (and can be re-configured) from the file `/etc/sudoers.d/010_pi-nopasswd`. This is done as follows:

  ```bash
  sudo visudo /etc/sudoers.d/010_pi-nopasswd
  # once your editor is opened, enter one line:
  pi ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
  ```

  This edit will work under *The Organization's* new default configuration for any userid you choose providing two things are true:

  1. the user is a member of the `sudo` group
  2. the file `/etc/sudoers` has the following line at the end of the file:

  > #includedir /etc/sudoers.d
  > note that the `#` is not a comment, but a #include

#### 3. With respect to your particular issues:

- **The file `/etc/crontab` is not intended to serve as the `root crontab`!**

  `/etc/crontab` is a *system wide* `crontab` with defaults that apply to all crontabs. ***You should not use it as the `root crontab`!***. Instead, the `root crontab` should be edited using the `sudo crontab -e` as shown above.

  You should also know that the `crontab` at `/etc/crontab` is also used to run the `cron` jobs under the `/etc/cron.hourly`, `.daily`, `.weekly` & `.monthly` folders. Some of these are important for your system's *"good health"*. You should take a look at them - there are several under `/etc/cron.daily`. Another reason not to edit the `/etc/crontab` file!
- Your other issue regarding your inability to make SSH connections as the `root` user seems to have been explained correctly in your accepted answer **:)**. As clarification for others who may read this, the problem seems to have been that your SSH client knew its *public key*, and `known-hosts` files were ***supposed to be*** in `/home/pi/.ssh`, but was *mis-directed* because the command was run by the `root` user. Your comment indicated that your issue was resolved by using `pi`'s `crontab` instead of `root`'s crontab (or `/etc/crontab` which also runs w/`root` privileges). However, some readers may be wondering: **How would this problem be solved *if* root privileges were needed in the script?***. I think there are (at least) three possible answers:

  1. Copy your `/home/pi/.ssh` folder to `/root`.
  2. Create a `/root/.ssh` folder from scratch.
  3. This *may be* an exception to **Rule 2** above; i.e. you do need `sudo` commands in a `user crontab`.

     It may be an interesting experiment?

---

#### Former answer:

As Milliways mentioned in his answer, your question is a bit short on details, but perhaps this will help:

1. Wrt `cron`, you must realize first that `cron` runs under a completely different `environment` than you do from your *login shell*. You can verify this for yourself, and get a record of your cron user's environment by running the `printenv` command; run it from your login shell (CLI) as follows:

```bash
$ printenv > myshellenv.txt
```

Now create a `cron` job by adding this line to your `crontab`:

```
* * * * * printenv > /home/pi/mycronenv.txt
```

Afterward, compare these two files & note the substantial differences!

I *suspect* that your error message `Host key verification failed.` is due to the fact that `cron` has no idea where your `~/.ssh` folder is. In general, there are two ways to handle this:

1. Use full path directives in your `crontab`, or
2. Define the PATH environment var in your `crontab`

This will work. If you still can't fiddle it, post some details & we'll respond.

Comment: I updated my question by removing some excess text and _hopefully_ providing more details. I problem is I don't know what details y'all need exactly. I have the full path directives defined and included a PATH environment variable but still the cronjob is not working.

Comment: @FruityFritz: Please post the entry from your `crontab` in another edit to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your Question(s) are not answerable because you have provided insufficient detail and no diagnostics.
In fact the Question is not Pi specific - it is a general Linux question and Questions should be restricted to a single issue.

You appear to be trying to run a couple of python programs then by some (unspecified) process using `ssh` access it.

Most of us doing remote logging would use a socket interface, but there is a common tool `mqtt` for this kind of task which does the job.

See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/105549/8697 for an example I use.

This code is intended to run from crontab and runs every 15 minutes.

The following is an extract from my crontab.

```
PYTHONPATH=/home/pi/bin/python
# This will publish into Broker on localhost
# Should Publish nothing if sensor missing
1,16,31,46 * * * * /home/pi/mqtt-dht11s.py
```

I have a second task to aggregate the data - this is run on the same Pi using `crontab` but it can be on any other computer by substituting an IP for `localhost`

```
6,21,36,51 * * * * /usr/bin/mosquitto_sub -h localhost -C 1 -t weather >> weather.log
```

There are very many tutorials. See https://mosquitto.org

Comment: I apologize: I did ask multiple questions and it does seem that my question is more general to Linux rather than RPi. I figured since I was running my script from a RPi to connect to others that it made sense to include it here. I have simplified my question and tried to include more relevant details but my knowledge of what is _relevant_ is limited.