# How can I connect a dht11 that uses digital input while also using an ADC converter and the SPI bus

Tags: pi-2

The source code I have below works for a two analog voltages(water level detection and temperature sensor). The code is set right now for just these two to run and it does work. If there is a problem the finally at the end will throw an error and I think this has something to do with the SPI bus. When I try to incorporate a dht11 temperature and humidity sensor that has a digital input, it will run for a couple seconds and then through the error. I tried it again and now it says that it is unable to set line (mcp = Adafruit....) to input. I think this problem is because both sensor are fighting over SPI bus for adafruit. I am not an expert programmer, I just want something that will work at the same time, so three total sensors(two channel voltages and 1 sensor output). Many lines of code I have commented out because I have combined different code. Some lines may be valuable for the temp and humidity sensor.

```
from time import sleep
import board
import adafruit_dht
import psutil
#
#import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

#import spidev
import Adafruit_MCP3008
#spi = spidev.SpiDev()
#spi.open(0, 0)
#spi.max_speed_hz = 250000

#GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
#GPIO.setup(14, GPIO.OUT)
#GPIO.setup(15, GPIO.OUT)
mcp = Adafruit_MCP3008.MCP3008(clk=11, cs=8, miso=9, mosi=10)
#sensor = adafruit_dht.DHT11(board.D23)



def poll_sensor(channel):
        """Poll MCP3002 ADC
        Args:
            channel (int):  ADC channel 0 or 1
        Returns:
            int: 10 bit value relating voltage 0 to 1023
        """
        assert 0 <= channel <= 1, 'ADC channel must be 0 or 1.'

        # First bit of cbyte is single=1 or diff=0.
        # Second bit is channel 0 or 1
        if channel:
            cbyte = 0b11000000
        else:
            cbyte = 0b10000000

        # Send (Start bit=1, cbyte=sgl/diff & odd/sign & MSBF = 0)
        r = spi.xfer2([1, cbyte, 0])

        # 10 bit value from returned bytes (bits 13-22):
        # XXXXXXXX, XXXX####, ######XX
        return ((r[1] & 31) << 6) + (r[2] >> 2)

try:
    while True:
       
        #temp = sensor.temperature
       # humidity = sensor.humidity
       # print("Temperature: {}*C   Humidity: {}% ".format(temp, humidity))
       
       #channel = 0
       # channeldata = poll_sensor(channel)

       # voltage = round(((channeldata * 3300) / 1024), 0)
        #print('Voltage (mV): {}'.format(voltage))
        #print('Data        : {}\n'.format(channeldata))

       # if voltage < 50:
            # Green
        #    GPIO.output(14, GPIO.HIGH)
        #    GPIO.output(15, GPIO.LOW)
        #elif voltage < 1800:
            # Yellow
         #   GPIO.output(14, GPIO.HIGH)
          #  GPIO.output(15, GPIO.HIGH)
       # else:
            # Red
          #  GPIO.output(14, GPIO.LOW)
          #  GPIO.output(15, GPIO.HIGH)

        print('Reading MCP3004 values, press Ctrl-C to quit...')
        # Print nice channel column headers.
       # print('| {0:>4} | {1:>4} | {2:>4} | {3:>4} | {4:>4} | {5:>4} | {6:>4} | {7:>4} |'.format(*range(8)))
       # print('-' * 57)
        # Main program loop.
   
        # Read all the ADC channel values in a list.
        values = [0]*4
        for i in range(4):
        # The read_adc function will get the value of the specified channel (0-7).
            values[i] = mcp.read_adc(i)
        # Print the ADC values.
        print('|Channel 0 ={0:>4} | Channel 1 ={1:>4} | '.format(*values))
         # Pause for half a second.
        sleep(0.5)

finally:                # run on exit
    spi.close()         # clean up
    #GPIO.cleanup()
    #print ("\n All cleaned up.")
```

Comment: This is strange program. You never call your function and never access dht.

Comment: What is the question? What is the error you get? For readability it is better to delete commented lines.

Answer (score 0):

DHT11 has nothing to do with SPI - it is a proprietary 1-Wire like protocol which can use ANY pin. The timing on DHT11 is critical.

In my experience the Adafruit code is unreliable (not to mention complex to setup and inflexible).

I use a version of Joan's DHT code.
See [Reliable temperature/humidity logging with Python and a DHT11](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/105548/reliable-temperature-humidity-logging-with-python-and-a-dht11/117225#117225)