# Unable to install Adafruit_DHT

Tags: adafruit

Running the Adafruit install command `sudo pip3 install Adafruit_DHT` results in the following error:

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting Adafruit_DHT
  Using cached Adafruit_DHT-1.4.0.tar.gz (15 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: Adafruit_DHT
  Building wheel for Adafruit_DHT (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [1 lines of output]
      Could not detect if running on the Raspberry Pi or Beaglebone Black.  If this failure is unexpected, you can run again with --force-pi or --force-bbb parameter to force using the Raspberry Pi or Beaglebone Black respectively.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for Adafruit_DHT
  Running setup.py clean for Adafruit_DHT
Failed to build Adafruit_DHT
Installing collected packages: Adafruit_DHT
  Running setup.py install for Adafruit_DHT ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Running setup.py install for Adafruit_DHT did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [1 lines of output]
      Could not detect if running on the Raspberry Pi or Beaglebone Black.  If this failure is unexpected, you can run again with --force-pi or --force-bbb parameter to force using the Raspberry Pi or Beaglebone Black respectively.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> Adafruit_DHT

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

Forcing Raspberry pi by running `sudo pip3 install Adafruit_DHT --install-option="--force-pi"` results in:

```
WARNING: Implying --no-binary=:all: due to the presence of --build-option / --global-option / --install-option. Consider using --config-settings for more flexibility.
DEPRECATION: --install-option is deprecated because it forces pip to use the 'setup.py install' command which is itself deprecated. pip 23.1 will enforce this behaviour change. A possible replacement is to use --config-settings. Discussion can be found at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/11358
DEPRECATION: --no-binary currently disables reading from the cache of locally built wheels. In the future --no-binary will not influence the wheel cache. pip 23.1 will enforce this behaviour change. A possible replacement is to use the --no-cache-dir option. You can use the flag --use-feature=no-binary-enable-wheel-cache to test the upcoming behaviour. Discussion can be found at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/11453
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting Adafruit_DHT
  Using cached Adafruit_DHT-1.4.0.tar.gz (15 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Installing collected packages: Adafruit_DHT
  DEPRECATION: Adafruit_DHT is being installed using the legacy 'setup.py install' method, because the '--no-binary' option was enabled for it and this currently disables local wheel building for projects that don't have a 'pyproject.toml' file. pip 23.1 will enforce this behaviour change. A possible replacement is to enable the '--use-pep517' option. Discussion can be found at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/11451
  Running setup.py install for Adafruit_DHT ... done
Successfully installed Adafruit_DHT
WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
```

However, running `pip show Adafruit_DHT` results in:
`WARNING: Package(s) not found: Adafruit_DHT`

Both my setuptools and wheel are update.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: This is very old code & not supported. It didn't even work well when it was current & Adafruit has abandoned it. See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/105548/reliable-temperature-humidity-logging-with-python-and-a-dht11