# DHT-11 doesn't work

Tags: gpio, adafruit

I connected a DHT-11 to the GPIO04 pin and wrote this code down.

```
import Adafruit_DHT

sensor = Adafruit_DHT.DHT22
pin = 7

while True:
    humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(sensor, pin)
    print(temperature, humidity)
```

It just prints None None and does nothing else. Thanks for all the help!~

Edit:
I ran this code

```
import sys
import pigpio
import DHT
import time
import datetime

# Sensor should be set to DHT.DHT11, DHT.DHTXX or DHT.DHTAUTO
sensor = DHT.DHT11

pin = 4     # Data - Pin 7 (BCM 4)

def output_data(timestamp, temperature, humidity):
    # Sample output Date: 2019-11-17T10:55:08, Temperature: 25°C, Humidity: 72%
    date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp).replace(microsecond=0).isoformat()
    print(u"Date: {:s}, Temperature: {:g}\u00b0C, Humidity: {:g}%".format(date, temperature, humidity))

pi = pigpio.pi()
if not pi.connected:
  exit()

s = DHT.sensor(pi, pin, model = sensor)

tries = 5   # try 5 times if error
while tries:
    try:
        timestamp, gpio, status, temperature, humidity = s.read()   #read DHT device
        if(status == DHT.DHT_TIMEOUT):  # no response from sensor
            exit()
        if(status == DHT.DHT_GOOD):
            output_data(timestamp, temperature, humidity)
            exit()      # Exit after successful read
        time.sleep(2)
        tries -=1
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break
```

and it came out as process ended as with exit code 0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reliable temperature/humidity logging with Python and a DHT11](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/105548/reliable-temperature-humidity-logging-with-python-and-a-dht11)

Comment: are you certain that the pin name is correct?

Comment: jsotola yes im sure

Comment: @Milliways 

Process ended with exit code 0.

comes out when i run the code

Comment: "Process ended with exit code 0" - what process? WHAT did you actually do? NOTE edit your question DO NOT put detail in Comments. The last time I used Adafruit code it did work, but was unreliable. NOTE it is unlikely to work if you connect to GPIO4 but tell the code you are using GPIO7.